# The iframe url opens on browser

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, iframe

My HTML iframe code

```
<iframe style="height:500px;width:500px;" src="http://google.co.in"><iframe>
```

if try show google in my webpage its through the error in console

**Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.**

Otherwise its works fine for many sites for example .,

```
<iframe style="height:500px;width:500px;" src="http://www.espncricinfo.com/">
```

***my problem is .,***

**when try load this URL(`www.dinamalar.com`) on `iframe` my webpage (redirected to www.dinamalar.com`)turn to homepage of particular website**

is there way to show this site on my web page's `iframe`..?you can try myURL in this try editor .  `iframe` not working in jsfiddle. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

this have to work in my page

```
<iframe style="height:500px;width:500px;" src="http://www.dinamalar.com/">
```

Comment: It's called a _framebuster_, and the purpose is exactly that: to prevent your page being displayed in (somebody else's) iframe.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz thanks for your valuable comment . can you explain about  'framebuster' and how to implement in our site..

Answer (score 1):

Wait for your site load completely and only then load your iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myframe").src="http://www.espncricinfo.com/"
});
```

UPDATE

Try this:

```
 <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('myframe').src = "//www.dinamalar.com/";
    }, 2000);
}, false);    
</script>
```

Comment: this was not working. have you tested..? if working try this src=http://www.dinamalar.com please?!

Comment: Sorry, I not tested ...

Comment: When loading my page again its redirected to www.dinamalar.com

Comment: Strange, if you remove the code above ... your page is not redirect?

Comment: My page redirect only for this site www.dinamalar.com  . other site  shows in iframe correctly . e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73329/discussion-between-j-srini-vasan-and-diego-gusava).